# A sufficient condition for a probability Borel measure to be nonzero on uncountable sets.

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces

Is there a (non-trivial) sufficient condition for a probability Borel measure $\mu$ on a metric space $(X, d)$ (where $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$) to be nonzero on **uncountable** Borel subsets of $X$? (Or is this actually *always* true?  I have no reason to believe this is the case.)

If it can help, we may take $X$ to be compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (w.r.t. to the Euclidean metric, but $d$ is still an arbitrary metric).

Comment: Cantor set is an uncountable set of measure $0$. In $\mathbb R^{2}$ the $x-$ axis is  an uncountable set of measure $0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see. I suppose you are using the Lebesgue measure for this?  Any ideas on a possible sufficient condition to get this property?

Comment: I don't think there is a reasonably easy nontrivial sufficient condition. A *necessary* condition is that there is no uncountable disjoint family of uncountable Borel sets in $X$. And the only easy way to rule that out that I immediately see is to require $X$ to be countable. But that gives a trivial sufficient condition.